# iOS4.3 Entitlements.plist for Ad Hoc Distribution

Tags: iphone, adhoc, entitlements

Ok, I've done three Ad Hoc distributions and each one has had its own problems in one way or the other, but this one has me completely perplexed. I've set everything up like I normally do, but after distributing the dreaded "Entitlements are invalid" error appears after attempting to install.

I'm using iOS4.3 and Xcode 4 GM 2.

I have Entitlements set up as follows:

[image]

(Source view):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Same as every Entitlement I've ever used. Confirmed that the Build has Code Signing Entitlements set to Entitlements.plist.

Get no error during "Archive" and no error generating the .ipa. Only on installation.

At a lose, any help would be appreciated.

Additional Note:

I tried setting the "application-identifier" and "keychain-access-groups" explicitly as mentioned in http://twoappguys.com/blog/ios4-and-the-wildcard/, but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: Are you using an other configuration instead of Release?

Comment: I duplicated creating "ad hoc"... but now that you mention it, I may have duplicated "debug"

Comment: You nailed it @mavrick3. Such a simple oversight! Plus, I'm not used to the new scheme management system. If you supply that as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using another configuration than Release, you need to review your Archive-Scheme and change it to your new Build Configuration.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of things that could be set wrong that would mess up your ad hoc distribution. For anyone still having issues with ad hoc distributions I wrote a detailed step by step to do this on Xcode 4 at http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1237

Answer (score 2):

Code signing entitlements are no longer necessary for Ad Hoc builds in Xcode 4 - see details notes in [Apple Technical Note TN2250](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING_GUIDE-CODE_SIGNING_ENTITLEMENTS)